# Dynamically add input field and use two database tables at once in dropdown select

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an select option that is dynamically added on a button click and a series of calculations for each row created, all is fetched from one database/table but i need to fetch an value from another table and use it in my calculations.

I need to get the Levy value from another table in the same database.

Javascript to dynamically add new rows and input fields.

```
var rowCount = 1;
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#add').click(function() {
rowCount++;
$('#orders').append('<tr id="row'+rowCount+'"><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'
+rowCount+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove circle">Remove</button></td><td><select style="width: 100%;" name="item'+rowCount+'" id="item'
+rowCount+'" class="browser-default custom-select-new"><option value="" disabled selected>Click to See Products</option><?php $records = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM customer_product WHERE customer LIKE '$Comid' "); while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) { echo '<option value="' . $data['product'] . '" data-new_price_rate="' . $data['new_total_rate'] . '" data-description="' . $data['description'] . '" data-tax="' . $data['tax'] . '" >' . $data['product'] . '</option>'; } ?></select></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="description'
+rowCount+'" name="description" for="'+rowCount+'"/></td><td><input class="form-control product_price" type="number" id="product_price'
+rowCount+'" name="product_price" for="'+rowCount+'"/></td><input class="form-control" type="hidden" data-type="product_id" id="product_id_'
+rowCount+'" name="product_id" for="'+rowCount+'"/><td><input class="form-control quantity" type="number" id="quantity_'
+rowCount+'" name="quantity" for="'+rowCount+'"/> </td><td><input class="form-control" type="number" id="tax'
+rowCount+'" name="tax"  for="'+rowCount+'"/> </td><td><input class="form-control" type="number" id="levy'
+rowCount+'" name="levy"  for="'+rowCount+'"/> </td><td><input class="form-control total_cost" type="text" id="total_cost_'
+rowCount+'" name="total_cost"  for="'+rowCount+'" readonly/><input hidden class="form-control tax_all" type="text" id="tax_all_'
+rowCount+'" name="tax_all" for="'+rowCount+'" readonly/><input hidden class="form-control totalBefore" type="text" id="totalBefore_'
+rowCount+'" name="totalBefore" for="'+rowCount+'" readonly/></td></tr>');
});
});
```

Calculations

```
// Using a new index rather than your global variable i
function getTotalCost(ind) {
var qty = $('#quantity_'+ind).val();
var levy = $('#levy'+ind).val();
var price = $('#product_price'+ind).val();
var tax = $('#tax'+ind).val();
var tax_totNumber = (qty * price) * tax;
var before_tax = qty * price;
var totNumber = tax_totNumber + (qty * price) + (qty * levy);
var tot = totNumber.toFixed(2);
$('#total_cost_'+ind).val(tot);
$('#tax_all_'+ind).val(tax_totNumber);
$('#totalBefore_'+ind).val(before_tax);
calculateSubTotal();
calculateTax();
calculateBeforeTax();
}
```

Get the value of select options

```
for(let i=1; i<25; i++) {

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 

let mySelect = document.getElementById("item" + i);

if (mySelect !== null) {

mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("product_price" + i).value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-new_price_rate"))
mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("description" + i).value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-description"))
mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("tax" + i).value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-tax"))
mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("levy" + i).value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-levy"))

console.log(mySelect);

}
});
}
```

Comment: There are much cleaner ways to accomplish this than using `getElementById` and numerically indexing HTML elements... but that aside what is the question?

Comment: if both tables have relation JOIN them in query and fetch values , btw the way js and php is combinate is very ugly and incomprehensible

Comment: The products are allocated to an category and each category has an value "levy" but there are no direct relations between them, three tables are used to complete the cycle

Comment: then join 3 tables product -> category -> levy values since this 3 table complete the cycle

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - you have `<input class="form-control"....` being generated outside of a table-cell which is incorrect. Also why assign a `for` attribute to the input elements?